# Get Class Type of Object and use it in a Variable Declaration

Tags: java

What I am trying to do, and I don't know whether this is possible, is to get the class type of an object, and then use it in a declaration. I am using the Gson library for Json Conversion and I want to create a method that can take any object Arraylist type and convert it into a JsonArray. What I have below is code. Arraylist of type X will are casted down to type Object and than passed to the method below. The INSERT_CLASS_HERE should be dynamic based on the Object type.

```
public static JsonArray getJsonArray(List<Object> list , Class theClass){

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    JsonElement element = gson.toJsonTree(list, new TypeToken<List<INSERT_CLASS_TYPE_HERE>>() {}.getType());

    if (! element.isJsonArray()) {
        try {
            throw new Exception();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    JsonArray jsonArray = element.getAsJsonArray();
    return jsonArray;
}
```

What I tried was the following but this isn't correct syntax and will throw errors

```
public static JsonArray getJsonArray(List<Object> list , Class theClass){
    if(list.size() == 0) return null;

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    JsonElement element = gson.toJsonTree(list, new TypeToken<List<theClass>>() {}.getType());

    if (! element.isJsonArray()) {
    // fail appropriately
        try {
            throw new Exception();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    JsonArray jsonArray = element.getAsJsonArray();
    return jsonArray;   
}
```

1) Is this possible to do, and if not why not?
2) If it is not, how can this be achieved?

Thank you!

Comment: If you cast it until it's an object, `.getClass()` will simply return object...

Comment: Also usually in Java, [generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) are used for this sort of thing

Comment: Then assume I pass the class type in as a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you passing in a type value? That should not be required.

```
public static JsonArray getJsonArray(List<Object> list){
    if(list.size() == 0) return null;

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    JsonElement element = gson.toJsonTree(list);
    JsonArray jsonArray = element.getAsJsonArray();
    return jsonArray;   
}
```

Better yet to avoid casting you can do the following

```
public static <T> JsonArray getJsonArray(List<T> list){
    if(list.size() == 0) return null;

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    JsonElement element = gson.toJsonTree(list);
    JsonArray jsonArray = element.getAsJsonArray();
    return jsonArray;   
}
```

Comment: @user1917363 What do you mean? The code I posted works unless there is some other unstated requirements.

Answer (score 1):

It seems what you are trying to do is along the lines of [Java generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/).

This should be fairly simply to do using generics:

```
public static <T> JsonArray getJsonArray(List<T> list){
    if(list.size() == 0) return null;

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    JsonElement element = gson.toJsonTree(list, new TypeToken<List<T>>() {}.getType());
    //Not familiar with gson, but you might be able to just use T here instead
```

Comment: @user1917363 fixed, you need a <T> in the method header

Answer (score -1):

Try modifying your method signature like this:

`public static <T> JsonArray getJsonArray(List<Object> list, Class<T> theClass )`

You should then be able to do this:

`new TypeToken<List<T>>`

Comment: Why leave the list type as object? Simply use the list for generics instead of bringing in an additional class object.